# When to join name and when not to?

Tags: naming-conventions

Most languages give guidelines to separate different words of a name by underscores (python, C etc.) or by camel-casing (Java). However the problem is when to consider the names as separate. The options are:

1) Do it at every instance when separate words from the English dictionary occur e.g. create_gui(), recv_msg(), createGui(), recvMsg() etc.

2) Use some intuition to decide when to do this and when not to do this e.g. recvmsg() is OK, but its better to have create_gui() .

What is this intuition?

The question looks trivial. But it presents a problem which is common and takes at least 5 seconds for each instance whenever it appears.

Comment: I asked for the second option, but no one answered that...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I always do your option 1, and as far as I can tell, all modern frameworks do.

One thing that comes to mind that just sticks names together is the standard C library. But its function names are often pretty cryptic anyway.

Comment: This. "Modern" is the key. Unless you have good reason to deviate, follow the two Java maxims: (1) don't abbreviate, and (2) don't jam words together. receiveMessage() is even better.

Answer (score 1):

I'm probably biased as an Objective-C programmer, where things tend to be quite spelled out, but I'd never have a method like `recvMsg`. It would be `receiveMessage` (and the first parameter should be of type `Message`; if it's a string, then it should be `receiveString` or possibly `receiveMessageString` depending on context). When you spell things out this way, I think the question tends to go away. You would never say `receivemessage`.

The only time I abbreviate is when the abbreviation is more clear than the full version. `createGUI` is good because "GUI" (gooey) is the common way we say it in English. `createGraphicalUserInterface` is actually more confusing, so should be avoided.

So to the original question, I believe #1 is best, but coupled with an opposition to unclear abbreviations.

One of the most foolish naming choices ever made in Unix was `creat()`, making a nonsense word to save one keystroke. Code is written once and read many times, so it should be biased towards ease of reading rather than writing.

Answer (score 0):

For me, and this is just me, I prefer to follow whatever is conventional for the language, thus camelCase for Java and C++, underscore for C and SQL.

But whatever you do, be consistent within any source file or project. The reader of your code will thank you; seeing an identifier that is inconsistent with most others makes the reader pause and ask "is something different going on with this identifier? Is there something here I should be noticing?"

Or in other words, follow the Principal of Least Surprise.

Edit: This got downmodded why??

Comment: Probably because it didn't answer the question? The question wasn't about whether camelCase or under_scores is better; it was about where to put word breaks.

Answer (score -1):

Just follow coding style, such moments usually well described.

For example:

```
ClassNamesInCamelNotaionWithFirstLetterCapitalized
classMethod()
classMember
CONSTANTS_IN_UPPERCASE_WITH_UNDERSCORE
local_variables_in_lowercase_with_underscores
```

Comment: I don't see why your answer got down voted, so modded up in compensation.